# Use Restrictions Payload **allowScreenShot** from configuration profile on IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, screenshot

Is there any way to use the **allowScreenShot** restriction payload inside and IOS app to disable screen captures?
I've been looking for a way to block screen captures on my IOS app and I came across with this document: [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf)

So I start wondering if it's possible to use this information inside an IOS app.
If someone knows the answer please help me with an example. Thanks!

Comment: No.  That is an MDM configuration profile payload, not an app configuration.  Preventing screenshots is essentially pointless while cameras are a thing that exist

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok I understand, thanks for your answer!